# FACING top/Bottom padding issue while Applying edge property to the view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, imageview, padding

Hey everyone I am trying to give edge effect to my view pager for which  I am  using  padding  in  viewpager which is resulting in white spaces on the top and bottom of image .I have already tried Adjustviewbound  and scaling property of image  on my view pager as well on the image view but no results .After applying padding it is resulting in padding on top and bottom as well in order to maintain the aspect ratio of the image .

Any type of help would be appreciated .!

View pager `

```
                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/av_medical_case_item"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="300dp"
                        />
```

pager Adapter

```
public class AdapterSliderImage extends PagerAdapter {

    public List<ModelImage> Images;

    Context context;
    String medical_id;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;




    public AdapterSliderImage(LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater, List<ModelImage> Images, Context context, String Id) {
        this.mLayoutInflater = mLayoutInflater;
        this.Images = Images;
        this.context = context;
        this._id = Id;
//        this.longestImage = findLongestImage();
    }

//    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
//        if (position == medicalImages.size()) {
//            return  1f;
//        }
//       return .8f;
//    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (Images != null)
            return medicalImages.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((FrameLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_case_image, container, false);
//        View view =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.view);
//        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        final FrameLayout frame_layout_iv = (FrameLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.frame_layout_iv);
        final ProgressBar img_loader_icon = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_loader_icon);
        img_loader_icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
//        frame_layout_iv.setClipToPadding(false);
//        frame_layout_iv.setPadding(0,0,30,0);

        Picasso.with(context).load(String.valueOf(Images.get(position).base_url)).into(imageView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                img_loader_icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {

            }

        });


        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(context, "Image number: " + position + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ActivityCase_.intent(context).isShowCaseSharePopup(false).isShowPublishReviewPopUp(false).case_id(id).flags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).start();

            }
        });


        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((FrameLayout) object);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

}
```

Layout Class for adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id ="@+id/frame_layout_iv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/img_loader_icon"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:paddingEnd="30dp"
        android:contentDescription="fdg" />
<!--<View-->
    <!--android:id = "@+id/view"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:background="@color/brand_light_green"/>-->



</FrameLayout>
```

Implementation of viewpager

```
 final ProgressBar pb_thumbnail_img = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb_thumbnail_img);
            av_item.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            iv_item_adjustable_view.setVisibility(GONE);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            List<ModelImage> ImageList = card.getImages();
            int max_height =  0 ;
            ModelImage longestImage = null;
            for (ModelImage image :ImageList ) {
                int height = image.getHeight();


                if (max_height < height) {
                    max_height = height;
                    longestImage = image;
                }

             }
                ImageList.remove(longestImage);
            ImageList.add(0, longestImage);
            final int orig_height = longestImage.getHeight();
                final int orig_width = longestImage.getWidth();


            av_case_item.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            av_case_item.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int req_width = av_case_item.getMeasuredWidth();
                    int req_height = req_width * orig_height / orig_width;
                    av_medical_case_item.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewPager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, req_height));


//                        av_medical_case_item.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

                }
            });

            AdapterSlider Image case_image_slider_adapter =  new =AdapterSliderImage(inflater, ImageList,getContext(),card.getItem_id());
//           
            av_case_item.setAdapter(case_image_slider_adapter);
            av_case_item.setClipToPadding(false);
            av_case_item.setPadding(0, 0, 60, 0);           `
```